# Creating a cone that has depth with spherical dimples that are on the inside mesh only

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

How can a create a cone with recessed spherical dimples on the inside mesh only (dimples similar to a golf ball).

I can create a cone with depth using the solidify modifier but how can I create recessed spherical dimples on the inside of the cone only?

**Please note: this is going to be 3D printed so I need to have some depth.**

[image: Cone]

Example of the dimples I'm trying to get on the inside mesh of the cone.
[image: Golf ball dimples]

Comment: the problem is that the pattern will be stretched on the Z axis on the top of the shape as the radius decreases, is it a problem for you?

Comment: @moonboots At this point I'm just trying to get any dimples to show up.

Comment: ok I've edited my answer, you can avoid with a trick, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is: Create the pattern, repeat it on the X and Z axis with an *Array* modifier, create a second wall that will be the outside wall, give the object a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode an 360°) to make it a cylinder. Keep a copy of the object somewhere, apply the the modifiers, join the top and bottom rims with a *Bridge Edge Loops*. Remove the doubles and clean the mesh. Now give the cylinder a *Mesh Deform* modifier with a cube as *Object*, scale and move down the top face of the cube so that it gives you a cone shape.

[image]

Problem with this solution is that the pattern tends to squeeze from the bottom to the top as the cone’s radius decreases. To avoid that you could first apply the 2 *Array* modifiers then move down the top edge with *Proportional Editing* enabled (*Linear* mode) so that it linearly squeezes the whole wall on the Z axis. Then give it the *Simple Deform* and *Mesh Deform*. This operation will compensate the *Mesh Deform* squeeze.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is select all the faces on the inside that you want to have the bumps/texture in edit mode. Then still in edit mode go and add a new material. It is important that you have 2 materials because by default the entire object will be the first material so make sure the first material you have is an outside material. Then add another material and press assign. To make the material use the normal principled bsdf in the shader editor. make a voroni texture and a color ramp. Add the color ramp to the base color input of the principled bsdf and connect the voroni textures color to the fac of the color ramp. duplicat the color ramp and voroni and connect it to a bump nodes height input and connect the bump node to the normal input of the principled node. change the voroni textures scale to 13.6 and in the color ramp make sure the black color's position is 0 and the white colors position is 0.279. Hope this helps!

edit: The end texture isnt symmetrical you will need to download an online map texture to have it symmetrical. There are places like polygon that i would suggest. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj7CJo2SzNA heres a good start for golf ball like textures